# Visual Basic Copying between word files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ms-word

I have a template word document and want to copy a certain set of paragraphs and headings from the 1st word template to a new word document. I have bookmarked all the different sections in the template(added bookmarks in MS Word)

I have implemented all the check boxes and menu systems in visual basic.
The check boxes decide which sections I want to copy from the template.but I don't know how to copy the text between the word files. can someone provide some information or a link

Am I on the  right track with this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx. but I could do with some help been stuck on this.

Comment: Would it be possible to just hide the bookmarks you don't want and save a new document, rather than the copy and paste? You should be able to do that through the word object model and more easily retain the style of the text.

Comment: @Matt Hi I programmed as you mentioned, everything works fine, except only the bookmark gets deleted and not the contents. how do I delete the contents that the bookmark covers. `objDoc.Bookmarks(required).Delete()` this is what i'm using to delete the bookmark, but only the bookmark within the new document is deleted.

Comment: Added an answer with an example of how to delete a bookmark's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this more easily by making a copy of the template document and then deleting the sections you don't want.

To save out a copy and use that (although using the template and then saving under another name should work as well):

```
File.Copy(template, copy)
objDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(copy)
```

You can delete the contents of a bookmark with something like this:

```
objDoc.Range.Bookmarks(required).Range.Delete()
```